# How to delete CRUD post using express

Tags: express

This is the way posts are rendered in the view. The delete post link is here also.

```
<ul class="posts" id="posts">
  <% for(var i = posts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { %>
    <li class="post">
      <span><a href="/myPage/<%=posts[i]['_id']%>"><%= posts[i].userCreate %></a></span>
      <!-- If current user created the post, show delete button -->
      <% if (user.username == posts[i].username) { %>
      <span><a href="/deletePost/<%= posts[i] %>">Delete</a></span>
      <% } %>
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Here is my route. A delete route causes an error. I think only a get route is valid for an href link.

```
// Delete post.
router.get('/deletePost/:id', function(req, res) {
    post.deletePost(req.params.id);
    res.redirect('crud');
});
```

This is the function I'm using to delete posts.

```
exports.deletePost = function(data) {
    postsCollection.findAndModify({data}, [], {remove:true}, function(err, object) {
        if(err)
            throw err;
        console.log("Deleted post!");
    });
}
```

This causes a 'too many redirects' error. And the post is not deleted at the end of it when my app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
router.delete('/delete/:id', function(req,res){
  myCollection.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
    if(err){res.send(err);}
    res.json({messaje:"Done"});
  });
});
```

Comment: findByIdAndRemove is not a function

Comment: findByIdAndRemove is a mongoose function. I supposed you are using that for store your data